Show that $\mathbb{R}$ in the finite complement topology is not Hausdorff.
I apologize as this question has been asked a couple times. I could simply copy a proof from someone else, but I am trying to improve my proof development as I am still new to constructing them. I am reading my first topology book and the title is the prompt of the question. My proof is:
Let $\mathbb{R}_{fc}$ be the finite complement topology. If we can find two neighborhoods, $x\in U$ and $y \in V$, where $U \cap V$ is non-empty, we can prove $\mathbb{R}_{fc}$ is not Hausdorff.
To begin, let $x,y \in \mathbb{R} : x\not= y$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$ and $V$ be a neighborhood of $y$. By the definition of $\mathbb{R}_{fc}$ we imply $\mathbb{R} - U$ and $\mathbb{R} - V$ are finite. Using DeMorgan's law, we can change our finite compliments:
\begin{align*}
    (\mathbb{R} - U) \cup (\mathbb{R} - V) \equiv \mathbb{R} - (U \cap V) 
\end{align*}
This implies $\mathbb{R} - (U \cap V)$ is finite. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite, $U \cap V$ must also be infinite. Thus, $U \cap V$ is non-empty and proves $\mathbb{R}_{fc}$ is not Hausdorff.
Not only would it be helpful to know if I am right or wrong, but also what styling preferences and some critiques to how I present my proofs, would also be just as valuable.
Thank you!

Endow $\mathbb{R}$ with the finite complement topology. The aim is to show that with this topology, $\mathbb{R}$ is not Hausdorff.
Consider any two distinct points $x$ and $y$. If $U$ and $V$ are open sets containing $x$ and $y$ respectively, then, $\mathbb{R}-U$ is finite and $\mathbb{R}-V$ is finite. If $U\cap V=\varnothing$, then, $\mathbb{R}$ would be finite, contradiction.

This is definitely a quicker elegant way. This can be good to integrate some ways to remove some superfluity in my own proof.
